# XmlUtil.serialize return not UTF8

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

code:

```
    def dataMap
    dataMap = [
                [No: '1', CustomerID: '777', Name: 'Lithuania: Ąęįėčęįasdad5645'],
                [No: '2', CustomerID: '888', Name: 'Latin: abcdefghij5646'],
                [No: '3', CustomerID: '999', Name: 'Russian: ааАСДАСЩХдсадсасд546']
              ]

    def date = new Date()
    def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

    def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    builder.setEncoding("UTF-8")
    def iFile = {
        mkp.xmlDeclaration()
        mkp.declareNamespace('xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
        iFile {
            Header {
                FileDescription {
                    FileVersion("rep-v1.2")
                    FileDateCreated(sdf.format(date))
                    DataType("F")
                    SoftwareName('reporting-api')
                    SoftwareVersion('2.0')
                    NumberOfParts("1")
                    PartNumber("BILLS")
                }
            }
            MasterFiles {}
            SourceDocuments {
                SalesInvoices {
                    for (row in dataMap) {
                        Invoice {
                            InvoiceNo(row.No)
                            CustomerInfo {
                                CustomerID(row.CustomerID)
                                Name("{!! htmlspecialchars(" + row.Name + ",ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_IGNORE | ENT_HTML401, \"UTF-8\") !!}")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    XmlUtil.serialize(builder.bind(iFile))
```

Problem is when I use:

```
XmlUtil.serialize(builder.bind(someFile))
```

my xml does not have UTF-8 characters. Have noticed on line (field row.Name after serialization scratch required other countries symbols)

```
Name("{!! htmlspecialchars(" + row.Name + ",ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_IGNORE | ENT_HTML401, \"UTF-8\") !!}")
```

Please help to solve that problem, seems it is java XmlUtil class problem, but why? Java is not Unicode (joke)?

```
builder.setEncoding("UTF-8")
```

does not working.

Comment: Do you have a small example of the problem that we can run? Do you see the same issue when you take grails out of the picture and try a small pure groovy example?

Comment: I am edit question with example. Self tested and looks like ok :)